# jquery change event lost focus to id, get id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input textbox id="inputChanges".  When the user clicks out of the textbox, the event fires and I can get the id of "inputChanges".  But, what I want to get is the id of where the user clicked outside of the textbox.  For instance, if I am in the input field and make a change and click directly on a button, I want the id of the button.

The following does not work for me, as it does not get the right id:

```
$(document).ready(function(event) {
    $("#inputChanges").change(function(event) {
        alert(event.target.id);
    });
});
```

Comment: if you want to get the id of an element that is clicked, you need to listen for a click event on that element

Comment: So shouldn't you be listening to the click on the button??

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to the button instead:

```
$("#button").click(function(e) {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen `click` event like this.

```js
   $(document).ready(function(event) {
$("#inputChanges").click(function(event) {
    alert(event.target.id);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inputChanges">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(event) {
    var focused = false;
    $("#inputChanges").focus(function(event) {
        focused = true;
    });
    $(document).click(function(event){
        var target = event.target;
        if(focused && target.id != "inputChanges"){
            focused = false;
            alert(target.id);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inputChanges"/>
<p id="paragraph">this is a paragraph</p>
<div id="div">this is a div</div>
```